# Stickem element breaking out of container

Tags: jquery, sticky

I'm using the jquery stickem library which I've never had a problem with.

I've placed the stickem-container on div's wrapper and the stickem class to the element I want to make sticky. I've looked at all the classes that it triggers, but can't figure out why it's breaking out of the main relative container.

```
                    <div class='grid-x grid-margin-x stickem-container'>
                        <div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 cell textCol'>Stuff here </div>
                        <div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 cell imgCol hide-for-small-only'>
                            <div class='stickem'><img src="<?php echo the_field('off_right_col'); ?>"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here's the documentation: https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem
Website: http://digital-dev.co.uk/cplaw-new/
It's the first image you see on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add the stickem class onto the image itself, didn't need a wrapper.